# A citizen's life as an investment project (from the State's PoV)

Tags: investment, macro-economics

An average citizen's life can be seen as an investment project: the State starts investing into prenatal care, the child's education etc., a young man starts making money and paying taxes (breaks even here), the overall balance goes positive but declines slightly in the end of life (a pension from the State).

Can I see stats on "closing balance" figures at least for US citizens? I bet such figures do exist. Can't google them out though, probably because of my not-so-good English.

Could you please point me to some info on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think such figure exist in its per-canned form. However, for the most part, any pension/social security/annuity provider needs to have an idea of that, since it is their current and future liability that we are talking about. A quick and dirty way would be to look at US Social Security's funds, and get an estimate of how underfunded they are (so you can get an idea of the true size of liability). Now if you divided that by current US population, then you will get perhaps the closest answer to your 'closing balance' figure. There are too many devils in the details to cover here, so if you want more granularity than this, you should first get comfortable with some life/pension actuarial concepts, which would be outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: Agreed. Economists such as Kotlikoff have attempted to come up with something along these lines https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_accounting but it is controversial and incomplete.